# How to get the $data in update($id, $data) in restful implementation of Zend framework 2

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2

How to get the $data in update($id, $data) in restful implementation of Zend framework 2

In the Postman, i am trying to send..

```
{   
    "gender":"1",
    "country":"1",
    "state":"2",
    "city":"23",
    "address1":"27,djkfhasdkjh,kjsdfhdkjs,kjsdh",
    "address2":"ksjadh f,sdkjfhjk",
    "postal_code":"627811",
    "birthdate":"11-12-2045",
    "phone":"0442805565",
    "mobile":"9865521557",
    "blood_group":"o-",
    "weight":"60",
    "height":"5.2",
    "bmi":"10",
}
```

and my rest code is:

//update :: update
public function update($id, $data) {

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type");

$data = json_decode($data);
print_r($data); 


if(empty($data)){
        $resp = array('status' => 'failure', 'errorCode' => 516, 'errorMessage' => 'json code format error');
        return new JsonModel($resp);
    }

    if ((strlen($data->mobile) >= 10) && (is_numeric($data->mobile))) {

    }
    else{
        $resp = array('status' => 'failure', 'errorCode' => 517, 'errorMessage' => 'mobile validation error');
        return new JsonModel($resp);
    }

    if(($data->gender == '1') || ($data->gender == '2')){

    }
    else{
        $resp = array('status' => 'failure', 'errorCode' => 517, 'eerorMessage' => 'gender validation error');
        return new JsonModel($resp);
    }


$id  = $this->params('id');


    $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $usersService = new UsersService($dbAdapter);
    $resp = $usersService->update($data,$id);
    $resp = array('status' => 'success');
    return new JsonModel($resp);    
exit;
```

Thanks,

Comment: What is the problem? What is the response of the application for your request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case (`PUT` request mapping to the `update` method) the `AbstractRestfulController` will get data from the [`processBodyContent`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractRestfulController.php#L568) method [on line `419`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractRestfulController.php#L419)

This method will check for the correct content type (`application/json`) using the [`requestHasContentType`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractRestfulController.php#L466) method. So if you set the `Content-Type` headers in your request to `application/json` the `$data` variable in your controller should be populated automatically.

So in your postman make sure you have the `Content-Type` header set:

[image]

> Note: You **don't** have to **decode** json data yourself, this is handled in the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, acually i used to filter the data like like this,

Comment: Thanks for the advice, actually i used to filter the data like like this,      also check my question how i filtered the data, am i doing right. Thanks

Comment: Do i  need to change the code like this.. if ((strlen($data['mobile']) >= 10) && (is_numeric($data['mobile']))) { // code }

Comment: You should seriously consider using inputFilters ([`Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.input-filter.intro.html)) for this and also take a look at [`ApiProblem`](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-api-problem) module. Maybe you should consider using [`Apigility`](https://apigility.org/)?

Answer (score -1):

```
class MyController extends AbstractRestfulController
{
    public function update($id, $data)
    {
        var_dump($id, $data);
    }
}
```

Send JSON to url .../mycontroller/1

{"data":"15"}

Method PUT

Content-Type: application/json

```
output:
array(1, 'data' => 15);
```